# Get a text file specific field issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on python in order to use data mining on social media to analysis data . 
Now I have written a code which gives me information about Facebook most liked pages and I have stored information on a text file called `"pages.txt"` the following is  a snapshot of my text file content :

```
{
 "paging": {
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=1&type=page&q=%26&locale=ar_AR&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAFxVPV6lJ43O6MABoxVrrHlb01rBNmpVf8ZCK0M1QlsEJ6yRZBWlzjf0vA1eX6YdwNHF2TLZBsECdg6Q8mI3BH3n5QTMsi55KtkCtOCd36AVxjZA7PXBL3mZA6FsLZCNp9IZCItCI4YVhCeikubnwCLpE0nSTOcKXR8DUzcZA4qZCBW92yoCDFk2z0eZBNSUU6lgZDZD&offset=1&__after_id=6127898346"
 }, 
 "data": [
  {
   "category": "\u0627\u0644\u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645", 
   "name": "The London School of Economics and Political Science - LSE", 
   "category_list": [
    {
     "id": "108051929285833", 
     "name": "\u0627\u0644\u0643\u0644\u064a\u0629 \u0648\u0627\u0644\u062c\u0627\u0645\u0639\u0629"
    }, 
    {
     "id": "187751327923426", 
     "name": "\u0645\u0646\u0638\u0645\u0629 \u062a\u0639\u0644\u064a\u0645\u064a\u0629"
    }
   ], 
   "id": "6127898346"
  }
 ]
}
```

Now I am wondering how can I get a specific field from it (e.g "id": "6127898346" ) ? I have tried a lot but I couldn't find a way to do .
I have written this so far :

```
ins = open( "pages.txt", "r" )
values = []
for line in ins:   
    values.append(line) 

ins.close()
print values
```

but this gives me  the whole line  any help?

Comment: Do you know this is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data?

Comment: You can use multiple for loops to get specific info.Now I'm thinking of an easy to understand algorithm to do that. Just give me a second.

Comment: @HussainTamboli: YUP I know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INFILE = open("pages.txt","r")
file = INFILE.readlines()

listA = []
ID_List = []
for line in file:
        if (line[6:8] =="id"):
        line = line.strip()
        listA.append(line)
    for id in listA:
        item = id[7:-2]
        item = item.strip()
        if item not in ID_List:
            ID_List.append(item)
print "List of all IDS:",ID_List
```

After running this on the file, I get:

```
>>> 
List of all IDS: ['108051929285833', '187751327923426', '612789834']
>>>
```

Comment: This is not a robust way to do it, and should not be promoted.

Comment: @e-satis I understand that,but since arze ramade seems to be new to Python,I used this very simple way.It's very easy to understand,but it's not the best way.

Comment: If he is a beginer, that's a good reason not avoid giving him an aswer he can't assess.

Answer (score 2):

This is JSON. You can get your data by loading it with the `json` module:

```
import json
with open(your_file).read() as content:
    data = json.loads(content)
    # manipulate your data
```

`data` will be ordinary Python data structures such as nested lists, dict, strings and int, so you can manipulate them the usual way.

Comment: @e-saties: but Is there any query in order to enter paging field  ad then the data filed in order to get id filed. I have tried your code it does not help me.

Comment: When you ran my code, what did you get ? What did you try to get your information out of it ? What did you understand of it ? What did you not ? Did you get an error ? You need to give a lot of informations so we can help you.

Comment: but how to access category_list field?

Comment: You have a dictionary containing a key "data" pointing to a list. This list contains dictionaries, each of them have a key "category_list". Now if you don't know how to access a key on a dictionary or iterate on a list, you must learn that first and come back : it's very important in Python. If you do, accessing "category_list" means accessing a dict key, then iterate on the result, then for each item, access the item "category_list" key. You don't need anything special to do it, just regular dict/list manipulation. The hard thing is that they are nested, here.

Comment: Exercice yourself with dumb data first. Train in a terminal by putting a list in a dictionary, and accessing the list items : `data = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}`. Try to get `6` out of this. Then, when you are able to do it, put dictionaries in the list, and try to access the dictionaries : `data = {'a': [{1: True, 2: None}]}`. Try to get `True` out of this. Once you got that, you will be able to solve your problem.